# how to fix: typeerror: 'Catg_id' is an invalid keyword argument

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

On running the above code, i get error:

```
TypeError: 'Catg_id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" for the function named as 'ch' above.
```

How to fix this error?

```
from categories.models import Catg, Type, Product, Choice
from django.shortcuts import render

def ch(request, Type_id, Product_id, Catg_id):
    ca = Catg.objects.get(pk=Catg_id)
    p = Type.objects.get(pk=Type_id)
    cho = Product.objects.get(pk=Product_id)
    alls = Choice.objects.all()
    context3 = {
        'p': p,
        'alls': alls,
        'cho': cho,
        'ca': ca,
    }
    return render(request, "service providers.html", context3)
```

ALSO IN URLS.PY

```py
url(r'^categories/(?P<Catg_id>[0-9])/(?P<Type_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<Product_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.Choice, name='choice'),
```

AND IN MODELS.PY

```py
class Choice(models.Model):
    chname = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chn = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=" ")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.chn
```

Comment: Where is views.Choice defined? The url should reference the function ch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to my comment, you would need something like

```
import views

url(r'^categories/(?P<Catg_id>[0-9])/(?P<Type_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<Product_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.ch, name='ch'),
```